# How to get all the cids and cache bin's in drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal-7

I have some troubles in my drupal system lately.
So I want to investigate drupal basic features about cache system.
But I can't find how can I get all the cache bin's.

I'd like to know this bin's because I want to use `cache_get_multiple` function.
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21cache.inc/function/cache_get_multiple/7.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are Parameters which you can use according to your needs.

$cid: The cache ID of the data to retrieve.

$bin: 'cache_block', 'cache_bootstrap', 'cache_field', 'cache_filter', 'cache_form', 'cache_menu', 'cache_page', 'cache_path', 'cache_update' or 'cache'.
and for the default cache use 'cache'.

Return value
The cache or FALSE on failure.

Parameters can set in below function accordingly.

```
function cache_get_multiple(array &$cids, $bin = 'cache') {
  return _cache_get_object($bin)->getMultiple($cids);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, Avinash. I want to know how to get all of the cid's from cache. Do you know it?

Comment: you need to pull data either from third-party API or from database.

Comment: I can get cids! But I think it is good to have this feature in Drupal basic feature. We need to connect database. Anyway my problem was resolved!